# Updating the value of a label text everytime a tableview refreshes

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am trying to implement a "subtotal" label to my program where I have a cart(array of cart objects) in a tableview that functions as it should, with the + and - buttons also working and the table view refreshing everytime the array is changed. I want to make it so every time the tableview is refreshed, the value of the label text refreshes to the subtotal(Total of all the items in the cart).

Here is the Cart class where the subtotal of each individual item would be computed by the quantity*price.

```
import Foundation
class Cart {
    var name: String
    var thumbnails: String
    var price: String
    var quantity: Int
    init(name: String, thumbnails : String, price : String, quantity:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.thumbnails = thumbnails
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity
    }
    
}
```

And here is the view controller class where the totalPrice IBOutlet is the label that I want to be dynamically changed based on when the cart is updated

```
import UIKit
var cartArray =  [Cart(name: "initial", thumbnails: "sgA1.jpg", price: "initial", quantity: 0)]
{
    didSet {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "cartArrayUpdated")))
        }
        
    
}


class CartViewController: UIViewController{
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var totalPrice: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.reloadData()
        NotificationCenter
        .default
        .addObserver(self,
                     selector: #selector(refresh),
                     name: .init("cartArrayUpdated"),
                     object: nil)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
    @objc func refresh() {
        print("refreshed")
        tableView.reloadData()
       

}
    
}
    extension CartViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
         ///code for implementing the cart (useless for the problem)
    }
```

I want to be able to change the text of the label each time the cart is updated... I tried to make a for loop in the "objc refresh" function to add up all the quantity*prices of each individual cart in the cartArray, but this wouldn't work. If you could advise me on how to solve my problem that would be great!

Comment: When you say adding things up wouldn't work, can you give more detail?  What did you try and in what way didn't it work?

Comment: You don't have to refresh the tableview. Whenever the '+' (or '-') is clicked, calculate the total and then set the totalPrice.text to the result value.

Comment: For some reason, when I tried to convert my price, which is a string, to a double to do the math,there were lots of errors such as nil, and then it simply wouldn't return the price as a double... How do I fix this?

Comment: Alright, I figured out how to do it, turns out my issue was that my price string contained the "$" symbol so it couldn't turn into a double... I just had to remove the $ from each price value when adding it, and it fixed!